# Display the date of the countup

Tags: javascript, html

As stated in the title, i'm looking to display the date since the countup has started counting.
Here is the code i got off from the internet:

```
<html> 
<header>
    <marquee meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf8"  Class="Scroller" behavior="scroll" direction="left" width="100%" height="50" scrollamount="8" scrolldelay="0" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()">
    <font size="5" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
    <strong>
    <em>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var montharray = new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")

        function countup (yr, m, d) {
            var today = new Date()
            var todayy = today.getYear()
            if (todayy < 1000)
                todayy+=1900
            var todaym = today.getMonth()
            var todayd = today.getDate()
            var todaystring = montharray[todaym]+" "+todayd+", "+todayy
            var paststring = montharray[m-1]+" "+d+", "+yr
            var difference = (Math.round((Date.parse(todaystring) - Date.parse(paststring)) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) * 1)
            difference += " jours"
            document.write("<FONT COLOR='RED'>Nombre de jours sans accident : " + difference + "  Dernier Accident le XX Accident sans arrêt. En chargeant son véhicule, la main du technicien a heurté un tuyau en inox, lui occasionant une plaie au doigt </FONT>")
        }
        //Entrer la date AAAA/MM/JJ
        countup(2016, 05, 04)
        </script>
    </em>
</header>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This html code intends to display information of the last work accident in my company
The countup works fine, what I would like displayed after the "document.write" is the date set in the "countup" in this example 2016/05/04, is there anyway to do this, or do i have to manually insert my date where the XX are written down?

Comment: have you tried adding `document.write(yr+"/"+m+"/"+d);` after first document.write ?

Comment: I'm probably doing this wrong
I tried document.write(yr+"/"+m+"/"+d)("<FONT COLOR='RED'>Nombre de jours sans accident .... and whats displayed is only the date
If i replace the "XX" by (yr+"/"+m+"/"+d); the return value is NaNa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var montharray=new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");

    function countup(yr,m,d){
        var today = new Date();
        var todayy = today.getYear();
        if (todayy < 1000) {
            todayy+=1900;
        }
        var todaym = today.getMonth();
        var todayd = today.getDate();

        var todaystring = montharray[todaym]+" "+todayd+", "+todayy;
        var paststring = montharray[m-1]+" "+d+", "+yr;
        var difference=(Math.round((Date.parse(todaystring)-Date.parse(paststring))/(24*60*60*1000))*1);
        difference+=" jours";
        
        var date = yr+'/'+m+'/'+d;

        document.write("<FONT COLOR='RED'>Nombre de jours sans accident : "+difference+" Dernier Accident le "+date+" Accident sans arrêt</FONT>");
    }

//Entrer la date AAAA/MM/JJ
countup(2016,05,04);
```

```html
<marquee meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf8"  Class="Scroller" behavior="scroll" direction="left" width="100%" height="50" scrollamount="8" scrolldelay="0" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()">
```

Comment: I had to fiddle arround to get the date incorporated Inside document.write and it works like a charm.
 
var date = todayy+'/'+todaym+'/'+todayd;
document.write("<FONT COLOR='RED'>Nombre de jours sans accident : "+difference+"  Dernier Accident le "+date+" Accident sans arrêt...</FONT>");

I'd like to thank both Håken Lid & jserodio for resolving my issue

Comment: I modified a bit my answer so now the date is displayed in red color. Also added +1 to your `var todaym = today.getMonth()` because month is starting in zero.

Comment: I actually have an issue with the countup now.
The countup date is 2016/05/04, and whats showed up is 2016/05/30

Comment: Ok there you have. Reload the answer.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, sorry if i wasn't clear enough about my need.
Thank you so much!